# GreatMaps support layer?

Tags: c#, .net, maps, gis, layer

Someone knows if the control of https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/ allows you to handle the concept of layers of information and basic actions such as duplicating layers, making them visible or not, making them editable, cloning them, making spatial selections and others, everything On the same control, that is on the graphical interface.

The disclaimer about the functionality of this component is really skewed.

Answer (score 1):

If your questions is - can the control do all of these things? The answer is yes, it can.

Each layer is a class which can be added to the map. Each marker, polygon, or route is a class which can added to the layer, and so you can create as many as you would like. You are only limited by memory and processing speed for displaying graphics.

Comment: There is some place to check this type of functionality, either with documentation, examples or similar?
Something that arouses suspicion is the fact that this component according to codeplex has not received an update for more than a year.

Have you had any positive experiences with this map control?

I appreciate your comments

Comment: For being an open-source control, it is fantastic. There are several tutorials available to get you started, for instance: http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/.  If nothing else, it is open source so you can add and edit as you like to meet your needs. I have had great success with this.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried layers with GMap.NET, but have used this repo. It has all flexibility to implement mentioned features.

You can read this post https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/279790